# Print a 5by5 matrix in MIPS using 1 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, mips

```
.data

spaceChar: .asciiz  " " 

#array of 26 elements 1,0,0,0,0  elements = 5*5
array: .word 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9
size: .word 25
endl: .asciiz "\n"

.text

main:

lw $t3, size

la $t1, array # get array address

li $t2, 0 # set loop counter

print_loop:

beq $t2, $t3, print_loop_end # check for array end

li $t5,4 #at 4th element I want next line
beq $t5,$t2,newline #checking..

lw $a0, ($t1) # print value at the array pointer

li $v0, 1

syscall

la $a0, spaceChar   # Display a space character between elements
li $v0, 4
syscall


addi $t2, $t2, 1 # advance loop counter

addi $t1, $t1, 4 # advance array pointer

j print_loop # repeat the loop


print_loop_end: 
li $v0,10
syscall

newline:
la $a0,endl
li $v0,4
syscall
j print_loop
```

Im trying to print a 5*5 matrix in MIPS This is a 1 dimensional array in mips of 25 elements, Im traversing through the elements in print_loop and when it hits the 4th element I want to do next line but when I run this (MARS 4.5) is freezing I dont know what Im doing please help

Comment: When you beq to newline, you don't change t2, so you loop infinitely prints newlines

Comment: THANK YOU I was hitting my head around this finally figured it thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You're infinitely looping on newline.

**Long answer:**

The problem is

```
beq $t5, $t2, newline          #checking
```

Once your counter gets 4, it keeps going to newline

```
newline:
la  $a0, endl
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   print_loop
```

Then it goes back to print_loop

```
print_loop:
beq $t2, $t3, print_loop_end   #check for array end
li  $t5, 4                     #at 4th element I want next line
beq $t5, $t2, newline          #checking
```

Uh-oh. We're back to our beq again! If you use the step-by-step debugger (the green arrow with a 1 next to the green arrow that runs), you'll see that you print the first row and then infinitely print newlines. Looks to me like you could just add another label in there after that beq.

In the future, I'd suggest commenting every single line and dividing code into chunks that complete objectives. For example:

```
# print value at the array pointer
lw  $a0, ($t1)    # print array[index]
li  $v0, 1        # syscall: print integer
syscall

# print space
la  $a0, spaceChar  # print character " "
li  $v0, 4          # syscall: print string
syscall
```

It's tedious, but it'll helps you sniff out bugs when everything is written in pseudocode. (plus, when someone asks a MIPS question on stackoverflow that you want to answer in a couple years, it helps you remember what the commands do! :P)

Oh, and you can just do

```
beq $t2, 4, newline
```

instead of

```
li  $t5, 4
beq $t5, $t2
```

MIPS can be tricky. Just take it slow and document EVERYTHING. Good luck!